# Fail to get value with tier.Next(&result) when using golang mongo without indexes in collection, get value if index stetted

Tags: mongodb, go

I get a question when using go mongo operation.

My code is like this:

```
iter = coll.Find(filter).Sort("-timestamp").Skip(12510).Limit(10).Iter()
for iter.Next(&result){
    ....
}
```

I have 12520 documents in collection, but fail to get value with `iter.Next()`, if I have not set the index of `timestamp` in MongoDB.
If I set index of "timestamp", it seems work, and I can get value in result.

So, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your data first then iterate it

here item is your struct of data you get from MongoDB

```
if err := iter.Decode(&item); err != nil {
return status.Errorf(
codes.Aborted,
fmt.Sprintln(errormsg.ERR_MSG_DATA_CANT_DECODE, err))
}
```

then do iteration it will works !!!

Comment: I now use the package `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` and it seems no function of `iter.Decode()`.
Also, in my code, Next(&item) will decode instead.
If Decode is the reason, adding indexes won't fix the problem, I think.
thanks for your answer : )